# Get a SUM of the dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a column at the end showing the SUM of the dynamic month columns. Currently I am getting columns showing the last 12 months from today but I want a final column to show the final sum of those values.

```
declare @start DATETIME = (select  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0)) 
declare @end DATETIME = (select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
declare @v_columns varchar(max)
declare @v_sql varchar(max)


;with months (v_date)
AS
(
    SELECT @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,v_date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,v_date)<=@end
)
select @v_columns=stuff((select','+QUOTENAME(DATENAME(month,v_date)+cast(year(v_date) as varchar)) from months for xml path('')),1,1,'')
--print @v_columns
set @v_sql='
;with months (v_date)
AS
(
    SELECT cast('''+convert(varchar(10),@start,101)+''' as date)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,v_date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,v_date)<='''+convert(varchar(10),@end,101)+'''
)
SELECT 
ITEMNUMBER,PRODUCTDESCRIPTION,PRODUCTGROUP_CUSTOM,PRODUCTLIFECYCLESTATEID,PRIMARYVENDORACCOUNTNUMBER,ALTERNATIVEITEMNUMBER,ORDEREDQUANTITY,WAREHOUSELOCATIONID,DATAAREAID,AVAILABLEONHANDQUANTITY'+@v_columns+'
FROM 
(


SELECT 
b.ITEMNUMBER,d.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION,b.PRODUCTGROUP_CUSTOM,b.PRODUCTLIFECYCLESTATEID,b.PRIMARYVENDORACCOUNTNUMBER,b.ALTERNATIVEITEMNUMBER,e.ORDEREDQUANTITY,c.WAREHOUSELOCATIONID,b.DATAAREAID,e.AVAILABLEONHANDQUANTITY, SUM(ISNULL(a.QTY,0)) [LineAmount],DATENAME(month,a.invoicedate)+cast(year(a.invoicedate) as varchar) as v_date
from dbo.Table1 b

inner join Table2 a
on a.ITEMID=b.ITEMNUMBER
inner join Table3 c
on b.itemnumber=c.ITEMNUMBER
inner join Table4 d
on b.ITEMNUMBER=d.PRODUCTNUMBER
inner join Table5 e
on b.ITEMNUMBER=e.ITEMNUMBER
where a.DATAAREAID=b.DATAAREAID 
group by b.ITEMNUMBER,d.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION,b.PRODUCTGROUP_CUSTOM,b.PRODUCTLIFECYCLESTATEID,c.WAREHOUSELOCATIONID,b.DATAAREAID,e.AVAILABLEONHANDQUANTITY,e.ORDEREDQUANTITY,a.invoicedate,b.PRIMARYVENDORACCOUNTNUMBER,b.ALTERNATIVEITEMNUMBER) as x
PIVOT
(
 SUM(LineAmount) FOR v_date IN ('+@v_columns+')
) PVT'

print @v_sql
EXEC (@v_sql)
```

Comment: You should really be parametrising the values for `@start` and `@end`, not injecting their values.

Comment: As for your question, this would be a lot easier if you use a Cross tab, rather than SQL Server's inbuilt `PIVOT` operator. Then getting a total sum is trivial (it's simply `SUM(YourColumn) AS Total`). [Cross Tabs and Pivots, Part 1 – Converting Rows to Columns](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/cross-tabs-and-pivots-part-1-%E2%80%93-converting-rows-to-columns-1). If you're stuck, you'll actually be much better off also giving us some sample data and expected results.

Comment: a fiddle is much helpful, with your input and above query, also post your expected output.